# Azure Cognitive Search SharePoint indexer - linking to the documents via SharePoint API

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-cognitive-search

I've got an ACS setup with SharePoint as the datasource. It's working well.

When I query the index and retrieve a document, I want to take that documents ID and query the sharepoint API to get additional information about that document. However, it seems that non of the identifiable information returned with the document (as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-sharepoint-online#indexing-document-metadata)):

| Identifier | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| metadata_spo_site_library_item_id | Edm.String | The combination key of site ID, library ID, and item ID which uniquely identifies an item in a document library for a site. |
| metadata_spo_site_id | Edm.String | The ID of the SharePoint site. |
| metadata_spo_library_id | Edm.String | The ID of document library. |
| metadata_spo_item_id | Edm.String | The ID of the (document) item in the library. |
| etc... | ... |  |

is recognised by the the sharepoint api e.g.

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('XXXXXXXX')/items?$select=Id&$filter=Id eq '{metadata_spo_site_library_item_id}'
```

does not work, nor does any variation I have tried.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I am decoding the document key and keeping on the index each item it contains separately:

[image]

None of these provided ids identify the document in the sharepoint-api, unless I am using the wrong endpoint

Answer (score 1):

By default, Azure cognitive search index key field will be encoded.  So, the value will not be in readable format in search results. In this scenario, you need to add one more filed in index and map the key value to newly created filed without mapping function.
As I have some restrictions on my access, I could not index share point data here. Instead of that I have taken a blob storage and indexed the data.
The steps I followed are,

1. Created index for the data source of type blob storage.
2. Selected **metadata_storage_path** as key for the index.
3. Created indexer as shown below,

```
{

"@odata.context": "https://searchname.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexers/$entity",

"@odata.etag": "\"*****\"",

"name": "azureblob-indexer",

"description": "",

"dataSourceName": "ds01",

"skillsetName": null,

"targetIndexName": "azureblob-index",

"disabled": null,

"schedule": null,

"parameters": {

"batchSize": null,

"maxFailedItems": 0,

"maxFailedItemsPerBatch": 0,

"base64EncodeKeys": null,

"configuration": {

"dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata",

"parsingMode": "default"

}

},

"fieldMappings": [

{

"sourceFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",

"targetFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",

"mappingFunction": {

"name": "base64Encode"

}

},

{

"sourceFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",

"targetFieldName": "path"

}

],

"outputFieldMappings": [],

"cache": null,

"encryptionKey": null

}
```

4. As shown in above code, I am mapping the value of **metadata_storage_path** to another filed **path**
   [image]
5. Performed search on index and results are as shown below,
   [image]
6. As you can see in above image, **metadata_storage_path** is encoded and it is not in readable format. **path** value is not encoded and it is in the readable format.
7. In your scenario, I would suggest you to add a new field in index and map the new filed to it in indexer as I have done.
8. In this way, you can query in share point Api using that new filed value.

Comment: thanks for the reponse @vijaya. I've edit my question to show that I am keeping all of these ids in my index - none of them work to identify the document in sharepoints-api

Comment: @JTInfinite what is the key filed in your index and if possible, can you share your indexer definition

Comment: May I ask why do you need to perform an extra call to SharePoint? By using "query" parameter, you should be able to index custom metadata as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-howto-index-sharepoint-online#indexing-document-metadata. Verbatim: To index custom metadata, "additionalColumns" must be specified in the query parameter of the data source.

Answer (score -1):

According to my research and testing, you can use the following REST API to get the SharePoint document:

```
GET https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items({item_id})
```

More information for reference: [Working with lists and list items with REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#retrieve-specific-list-item)

-------------------------Update---------------------------

The "`item_id`" is the `ID column` in SharePoint list/library. For example:
[image]

You can display the `ID column` in Lists setting ->> Edit View.

You also can get `item_id` through the following REST API:

```
GET https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: from my testing, none of the field offered by cognitive search fit the requirements of your item_id - the document is not found

Comment: The "item_id" is the ID column in SharePoint List/Library.I have updated my answer, please check.

Comment: That id is not returned by the cognitive search indexer